# Issue with icons and a change in the electron.manifest.json is resulting in a crash

Tags: electron, electron-builder, electron.net

In my **asp.net core 3 electron.net app**, when I leave the default electron.manifest.json, it builds and runs well but **fails to use icons**.

Icons are set as **content** with **copy always** attribute.

However when I try to change the product Id and related information, **it crashes**.

```
{
 "executable": "Text Converter",
 "splashscreen": {
 "imageFile": "/wwwroot/assets/USFMConverter.png"
},
 "singleInstance": false,
 "build": {
 "appId": "com.CrossPlatformTextWebApplication.app",
 "productName": "Text Converter",
 "copyright": "Copyright © 2020",
 "buildVersion": "1.0.1",
 "win": {
  "icon": "/wwwroot/assets/icons/icon.ico"
   },
 "mac": {
  "icon": "/wwwroot/assets/icons/icon.icns"
  },
 "linux": {
  "icon": "/wwwroot/assets/icons"
  },
  ...
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's the name of executable.. does your project name have a space? Change it to a hyphen again... and then also in the electron.manifest.json file...